# problem about compactness

Tags: metric-spaces

If X is compact then so is C[X].(C[X] is the set of all continuous functions over X.)
Does there exit a Necessary and Sufficient Condition here ;does compactness of C[X] say anything about X?

Comment: Is $C[X]$ the space of real- (or complex-) valued functions on $X$, or of $X$-valued functions?

Comment: real /complex valued sir

Comment: Then $C[X]$ is never compact unless $X = \varnothing$. It is then always a (real or complex) vector space, with a Hausdorff topology. Such a vector space is compact if and only if it is the trivial vector space.

Comment: @learningmaths Under what topology on $C[X]$? If you mean under the topology induced by the supremum norm, the statement is false.